# getting this error: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch

Tags: php, vbscript, batch-file, odbc, oledb

We have a PHP script on our server that generates a batch file that is set to run at a specific time of day in Task Scheduler. The batch file calls a vbs file that contacts several computers through ODBC to retrieve data and insert it in our MySQL db. This has been working fine for weeks, but today I get this error message:

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

I don't know what this error means or how to fix it. Please help, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked many times on stackoverflow so try searching for architecture mismatch. You are attempting to mix a 32 bit application with a 64 bit ODBC driver or vice versa. See [64-bit ODBC](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/64-bit.html) and [Why do I get error "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"?](http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01028.html). You need to create a DSN using the right ODBC Driver Manager i.e., the 32 bit one or the 64 bit one depending on the architecture of your application. The 32 bit ODBC driver manager is located at %windir%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe